# How to pass subdomain to Controller or set global variable?

Tags: php, symfony

I would like to create pages for different clients. Every client would have different subdomain.

I would like to have client name globally from subdomain. Eventually I would like to pass this subdomain to controller.

```
website_app:
    resource: "@WebsiteAppBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    host:     "{client_name}.example.com"
    defaults:
       client: "%client_name%"
    prefix:   /
```

This approach doesn't work.

Using `kernel.listener.subdomain_listener` and setting parameter is impossible because of `Impossible to call set() on a frozen ParameterBag.`

Do you have any idea how to get subdomain and make it accessible globally?

Comment: You won't be able to make it a parameter since it can change on every request.  Your best bet would probably be to make yourself a listener and add the subdomain to the request object.  Then key off of that.